# Собственные функции. Не компилируется код. Подскажите, почему не определена переменная?

Tags: python-3.x, функции

Компилятор выдал:

```
version: 0.2  
author: smile  
Вас приветствует виртуальный банк  
капитализация банка  10000000000 $  
Владелец банка: Я  
Введите свой уровень дохода >>> 1  
Спасибо, Вы указали значение:  1  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "l09_hw02_virtBank.py", line 18, in <module>  
capital_01 = capital + money1  
NameError: name 'money1' is not defined
```

---

```
version = 0.2
author = 'smile'

def hello():
    print ("Вас приветствует виртуальный банк")

def money():
    money1 = int(input ("Введите свой уровень дохода >>> "))
    print('Спасибо, Вы указали значение: ', money1)

print ("version:", version)
print ("author:", author)
hello()
capital = 10000000000
print ("капитализация банка ", capital, "$" )
print ("Владелец банка: Я")
money()
capital_01 = capital + money1
print ("С вашими деньгами, у нас уже ", capital_01, "$")
```

Comment: Ну Вы ж определяете money1 внутри money() - там она по завершении выполнения процедуры и скончается...

Comment: @Akina, ... глобальные переменные зло, да? Можно было хотя из `money` возвращать `money1`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что функция money ни чего не возвращает...
Попробуй вот так:

```
version = 0.2
author = 'smile'

def hello():
    print ("Вас приветствует виртуальный банк")

def money():
    money1 = int(input ("Введите свой уровень дохода >>> "))
    print('Спасибо, Вы указали значение: ', money1)
    return money1

print ("version:", version)
print ("author:", author)
hello()
capital = 10000000000
print ("капитализация банка ", capital, "$" )
print ("Владелец банка: Я")
capital_01 = capital + money()
print ("С вашими деньгами, у нас уже ", capital_01, "$")
```

Comment: И главное помни, все переменные что ты объявляешь внутри функций - локальные, их нужно возвращать через return (в твоем случае)

Comment: Спасибо, все четко, ясно, понятно. Респект. Все работает.